# Why does phpmyadmin not export as sql ( UPDATE)

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

I am trying to export it as sql but it prints as mssql every time.

[image]

As shown in the picture, MSSQL prints out every time

I do a lot of research on the results of the work, but does not work

my .bash_profile

[image]

I use xampp and mac os sierra

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a bug related to the language localization. Have you tried submitting an issue on Github? https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Comment: I will try, but I have to find a solution. I have to hand in the project tomorrow

Comment: Do it from the command line: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

Comment: Thank you Jeremy ! , I try now.

Comment: Mysqldump is not available now

Comment: Ignoring the extension for just a moment, what is the actual content of the file; does it look like MSSQL or MySQL flavor of SQL?